# $DebugPreference = "Continue" not working when running a powersehll runbook in azure automation account's test pane

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, powershell-cmdlet

Earlier when I used to use command `$DebugPreference="Continue"` within the powershell script, this used to print the output with all the debugging lines. Now I am not able to see debug results in the test pane. And this is required to check where exactlty the powershell code failing and to know the exact error.

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts 
Import-Module Az.Resources 
Import-Module Az.Compute 
Import-Module Az.Automation 
Import-Module Az.Storage 
Import-Module Az.KeyVault 
Import-Module Az.RecoveryServices  
$DebugPreference = 'continue' 
Connect-AzAccount -Identity  
$context = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable write-output "context" $context Set-AzContext -Subscription "<<subscriptionID>>" 
$vaultName = "" 
$vaultResourcegroup = ""  
$containerCtx = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourcegroup   
write-output "containerCtx" $containerCtx
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/capture-debug-stream-automation-runbook

[azure](/questions/tagged/azure) [azure-automation](/questions/tagged/azure-automation) [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) [powershell-cmdlet](/questions/tagged/powershell-cmdlet)

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for resolving it? @Srishti garg

Comment: `Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.Compute
Import-Module Az.Automation
Import-Module Az.Storage
Import-Module Az.KeyVault
Import-Module Az.RecoveryServices

$DebugPreference = 'continue'
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

$context = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable
write-output "context" $context
Set-AzContext -Subscription "<<subscriptionID>>"
$vaultName = ""
$vaultResourcegroup = ""

$containerCtx = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourcegroup 

write-output "containerCtx" $containerCtx`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly given in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-output-and-messages) of configuring automation runbook output and message streams, `debug` logs will not be displayed in the `test pane` instead all the logs can be clearly seen after you `publish` the runbook.

*Note:* But `$VerbosePreference="continue"`functionality will display all the output verbose information in the test pane.

After checking the above doc, I tried executing your code in my automation PowerShell runbook (`7.1`) environment, published my runbook and then started executing a job as shown below.

[image]

[image]

```bash
$GLOBAL:DebugPreference="Continue"
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
$vaultName = "newvmjvault"
$vaultResourcegroup = "xxxx"
$containerCtx = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $vaultResourcegroup
write-output "containerCtx"  $containerCtx
```

*Debug logs are displayed after publishing a runbook:*

[image]

Comment: This is not working for me. I have tried to run the same code in powershell 7.1 version but it is not printing any debug statements. am I missing anything? @Jahnavi

Comment: How are you executing the code? Did you publish the runbook as I mentioned in the answer? @Srishtigarg

Comment: Yes, I created a new runbook with version 7.1 and published the runbook also. Then running the runbook using start option @jahnavi

Comment: After published it, did you click on refresh and then start? @Srishtigarg

Comment: ok, I give it a try. Is this something related to modules update also. Though, I have updated all the modules to the latest version @Jahnavi

Comment: No need. Just publish the runbook and once it is redirected to the output page just click on refresh continuously to generate the debug logs. @Srishtigarg

Comment: This is the refresh button I was mentioned. Refer [image](https://i.imgur.com/brGTtRT.png). @Srishtigarg

Comment: Are you able to make it work as shown in the above image? @Srishtigarg

Comment: I tried this using your method, it's not working for me. @Jahnavi

Comment: Can you let me know the process of your trial in detailed step by step procedure? Because it is working me with no issues. If you can provide me the steps, we can try to fix your issue. @Srishtigarg